# How can I use a value of a variable that is assigned to the variable in a previous if statement?

Tags: variables, button, if-statement, variable-assignment

This is code in Android Studio. I created Buttons start, higher and lower. The goal is to get the button "start" to show a random number guess. This initial random number has to be used when the buttons "higher" or "lower" are being pressed. But if I do it in the way below, it gives me the error that x is not initialized. I know this is because I assigned a value to x in another if-loop but I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    int x;
    int lowBound;
    int highBound;
    if (v==start) {
        x=(int) Math.random()*1000;
        myTextView2.append("Random guess is "+String.valueOf(x));
    }
    if (v==higher) {
        lowBound=x;
        x= (int) (lowBound+Math.random()*(1000-lowBound));
        myTextView2.append(" New guess is "+String.valueOf(x));
    }
    if (v==lower) {
        highBound=x; 
        x=(int) (highBound-Math.random()*(1000-highBound));
        myTextView2.append(" New guess is "+ String.valueOf(x));
    }

}
```

Comment: I now declared the random number outside the method. It still gives me "Random guess is 0". Also, every time the button "higher" or "lower" is clicked it should adapt the boundaries of the random number generator. This way, that doesn't work as well. Maybe my whole approach to the problem is totally wrong...

Answer (score 0):

If `v` is equal to anything other than `start`, the variable will assigned to `lowerBound` or `upperBound` uninitialized.

Unless I'm reading it wrong, this actually shows a flaw in your logic:

Every time `onClick` is called, `x` will either be reset if `v == start`, or will be used uninitiated.

`x` should declared outside of the method since you need it to "survive" between `onClicks`.